# SQL Server Express edition, prevent attach database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is there any way to prevent SQL server 2005 express, that someone has access to a database by attaching the .mdf in another instance?
The user has full access to the server, but not to the instance in which the database runs. The problem is that if you create another instance and copy the .mdf, can access database, adjuntandola in an instance which should you have access. Any ideas? I need it for sql 2005, 2008 express

Comment: Generally speaking, if you don't trust the owner of a system, you shouldn't put sensitive data on that system. Can you explain a bit why you want this, why you cannot or do not want to put the data on a trusted server and have clients connect to it?

Comment: Each client has its own server, which creates an instance for the database to which we don't give it access to ensure the integrity of the data. The problem is that if the client can access the database in any way, could get to introduce errors in this.

Comment: Sure, but that's normal. If the user starts overwriting random parts of files the user shouldn't be touching, things break. I don't think there's any hope of preventing that, definitely not reliably, but let's see if someone comes up with a somewhat good enough answer.